# ios auto renewal subscription and user in our service

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

In our service, each user has a username (email), password and a unique identifier. How can I link any purchases through Apples' **auto renewal subscription** to that user?

Is there any field that renders an Apple user as unique?
I don't want to link it to the device, because the user can run the app from many devices, so I want a unique identifier for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple does not provide you a unique identifier for an Apple user or Apple ID (probably to help protect the users privacy).  What I was doing was using their first Auto-Renewing receipt as their unique identifier.  So you should be able to use the `original_transaction_id` in your receipt verifications.  When you verify a receipt with Apple's servers, the response should include the transaction id of the original auto-renewing subscription that that user purchased from you regardless of which device they were on.  And I've found that even if a subscription lapses and then starts again, there will always be the one original auto-renewing transaction that is referenced.

It's a bit of a trick but it seems to work.

Alternatively, you could also use an iCloud key-value store to store a unique ID. That ID will be the same on all a user's devices, but they have to have iCloud turned on on all their devices. And technically they could be using different accounts for iCloud than they're using to make purchases so this isn't perfect.

Comment: I can't get `original_transaction_id` keys from response of apple server. My reponse have `lastest_receipt`, `lastest_receipt_info`, `environment` , `auto_renew_status` , `password` , `auto_renew_product_id`, `notification_type`, but missing `original_transaction_id`